# VSTO 4.0 Outlook AddIn signing

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

Users are getting a VSTO Exception while installing my addin on computers without my certificate installed (unknown certificate). The certificate is a purchased code signing certificate class 2, which is working on another application.

I create my installation files via ClickOnce. The ClickOnce setup.exe gets signed and I am signing the dll in the Post-build with

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin\signtool.exe" sign /f cert.pfx /p pw  "$(ProjectDir)obj\Release\myAddin.dll"
```

I want to deploy the addin via C# code in another application. If I register my Addin in the registry i get the above error.

If I run the setup.exe it is installing properly, but this is not a option since no silent install is supported.

How do I get rid of the error? Or is there any other way to install the Addin silently? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make the MSI from vistual studio using "Visual studio installer as a new project" in this wizerd link your project output to the Setup Project and copy the manfiest file manually into the dependencies folder of the Setup(the project you are using to make MSI).
then you can run the MSI as silent via Group Policy.
dont know if thats help but thats how i am doing currentaly for my project. 
Thanks

Comment: Yup i do, but you can live without it as well while you installing via MSI.